# SQL parse delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't find a good way to do this and because of some restrictions it has to be a coded without the use of variables but I can call a function. Anyway, I need to return a result set from a Select query and one of the rows is a pipe delimited string.

So, it will return something like:

```
id| Name      | Message |
---------------------
1 | Some Name | 'Here is my | delimited | message'
```

And I need it to be

```
id| Name      | Message1     | Message2    | Message3
------------------------------------------------------
1 | Some Name | 'Here is my' | 'delimited' | 'message'
```

I was thinking of something like `Parsename('','|',1)`, where you can pass in the delimiter instead of it always being a period but I don't know the best way to accomplish that.

EDIT: I've tried variations of this but of course it is very confusing. There could be 4 or more |

```
SELECT Field1, 
Field2 AS Originalvalue,
--1
SUBSTRING(Field2,0,CHARINDEX('|',Field2)) AS Msg1,
--2
LEFT(SUBSTRING(Field2,CHARINDEX('|',Field2)+1 ,LEN(Field2)),CHARINDEX('|',SUBSTRING(Field2,CHARINDEX('|',Field2)+1 ,LEN(Field2)))-1)
AS ExtractedValue
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T1.Id = 12
```

Comment: Why do people [keep doing this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+delimited)?!

Comment: pipe delimited fields make SQL fairies die

Comment: Hmm, do people not answer questions on this site? It seems to be a lot of 'go look at google'. I've been looking for over an hour now and I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user204588 You're not going to get a great answer (if you get one at all) because your design is extremely poor.

Comment: great, but it's not mine. It's what I have to work with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a sql function as follows.

```
create Function dbo.fn_Parsename(@Message Varchar(1000), @delimiter char(1), @index int )
Returns Varchar(1000)
As
Begin
    Declare
        @curIndex int = 0,
        @pos int = 1,
        @prevPos int = 0,
        @result varchar(1000)

    while @pos > 0
    Begin

        set @pos =  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @Message, @prevPos);

        if(@pos > 0)
        begin-- get the chars between the prev position to next delimiter pos
            set @result = SUBSTRING(@message, @prevPos, @pos-@prevPos)
        end
        else
        begin--get last delim message
            set @result = SUBSTRING(@message, @prevPos, LEN(@message))
        end

        if(@index = @curIndex)
        begin
            return @result
        end

        set @prevPos = @pos + 1
        set @curIndex = @curIndex + 1;

    end
    return ''--not found
End
```

And you can call it as below:

```
select dbo.fn_Parsename('Here is my | delimited | message','|', 0)
select dbo.fn_Parsename('Here is my | delimited | message','|', 1)
select dbo.fn_Parsename('Here is my | delimited | message','|', 2)
```

Comment: If your message is a column, would the formula still stay exactly the same? For example, would I write exactly: @delimitor, etc.? Also can I call the function for a full column and do something like this? `"select *, dbo.fn_Parsename(Message,'|', 0), dbo.fn_Parsename(Message,'|', 1) FROM table1`