# creating a report of how many times something occured

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I need to build a query from dates like:

```
2015-01-01 01:05:15  
2015-01-01 01:07:17  
2015-01-01 07:09:18  
2015-01-01 07:12:41  
2015-01-02 04:06:15  
2015-01-02 04:15:15
```

I need to have table in which there will be column for every hour and a row for every day of the month in which there will be the count of how many times did something occur during an hour.

For given example i`ll have data like this

```
2015-01-01|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|....  
2015-01-02|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|....
....  
....
```

I appreciate every advice.

Comment: What SQL version? Also - Will this table be more often written to or read from?

Answer (score 1):

First, create the table with those 24 columns; something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ROMPECABEZA
DATECOL DATETIME,
HOUR1 INT,
. . .
HOUR24 INT
```

Then you will need to perform some operations and insert values such as:

```
INSERT INTO ROMPECABEZA (DATECOL, HOUR1, ... HOUR24) VALUES (@DATECOLVAL, @HOUR1VAL, ..., @HOUR24VAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table like this

```
Create Table EveryDay
(
  Day date,
  Hour0 int,
  Hour1 int,
  ...
  Hour23 int
)
```

Then create a query that will read from the dates list, parse, and convert them and insert or update if it's not a one time thing.

Parse SQL with delimiter - [SQL parse delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924254/sql-parse-delimited-string)